# Scotch Panels: making a panel open "above", as an overlay

Tags: jquery, panel, scotch-panels

[This pretty known jQuery library](https://panels.scotch.io/) allows creating "collapsable" panels.

When the panels are opened - they "push" the other content aside,
and I'd like to have them open "above" the main content.

Take [this demo](https://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/EdaBm) as an example, click on the 3-lines menu in the corner, you'll see the content gets pushed.

Anyone know a way to make it come as an overlay above the content?

Adding `position:fixed` or `position:absolute` to the `<article>` simply makes it disappear completely.

Answer (score 0):

I've made modifications to the original code and implemented this functionality. 
More information in this fork:

https://github.com/yuval-a/scotch-panels